# Ruby Return the characters window given an string index

Tags: ruby, string

I am trying to get a window of characters from a string.

```
s="ABCDEFGH"
```

Given an index 4 of the string I would like to get the characters
`CDEFG` i.e two characters to the left and two characters to the right of the index position.

So I wrote this.

```
s[0..4][-3,2] + s[4,3] #=>"CDEFG"
```

But this does not feel very idiomatic and is sort of 'hackish', Is there a better and more generalizable way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class String
  def slice_with_index_and_around_chars(index, around)
    str_range = (index - around..index + around)
    self[str_range]
  end
end

s = "ABCDEFGH"
p s.slice_with_index_and_around_chars(4, 2)  #=>"CDEFG"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the two characters left and right of the index, just get that directly:

```
s = "ABCDEFGH"
index = 4
s[index - 2, 5]  # Get 5 characters starting 2 before the given index - 2 before + index + 2 after = 5
# => "CDEFG"
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use ruby's [negative indexes](http://rubyquicktips.com/post/996814716/use-negative-array-indices):

`s[2, -2]`